# What is the easiest way to build an IDE in java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, ide

i have to build an ide for my programming language , and i need to implement features like :

syntax highlighting , auto complete , line numbering , ...

so i need to know how to implement these features or if there is an existing components for code editing please refer to it .

thanks

Comment: Well what have you done so far, and what did your professor say to do?

Comment: @Woot4Moo ah yes, it is that time of year, isn't it?

Comment: If this is homework, please mark it as such.  If it is not homework, I believe glocoder covered it.

Comment: NetBeans Plugin? http://wiki.netbeans.org/How_to_create_support_for_a_new_language

Comment: i dont write any loc in the ide , i always ask for SO advice , and it doesnt  a homework .

Comment: @radi you should use an ide, it makes you far more productive I promise :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse has a nice framework for this:

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/

Comment: thanks , i need to know how to integrate my compiler (written in antlr) with xtext ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is there is no easy way to build an ide.

Some ideas:
Eclipse has a good framework as mentioned, 
you could make a plugin for notepad++, 
you could custom build SciTE.